# Python read console input using select on the same line

Tags: python, select, stdin, nonblocking

I need to use a non blocking way to read from the console. I successfully managed to do this using select

```
ready = select.select(read_list, [], [], timeout)[0]
read_list = [sys.stdin]
timeout = 0.1 # seconds
```

My problem now is that **I need to provide a text line (eg UI) before the input and would like the input cursor to be on the same line.** Before when I was not using select I could achieve this by doing:

```
buff = raw_input('                     ENTER CODE: ------\b\b\b\b\b\b')
```

In this way **the cursor would have been just after the comma (eg. on the first '-')**

Now that I need to use **stdin**, the cursor always goes at the beginning of a new line. Even if I do:

```
print('                     ENTER CODE: ------\b\b\b\b\b\b\r')
while read_list:
        ready = select.select(read_list, [], [], timeout)[0]
        if not ready:
            idle_work()
        else:
            for file in ready:
                line = file.readline()
                if not line: # EOF, remove file from input list
                    read_list.remove(file)
                elif line.rstrip(): # optional: skipping empty lines
                    #treat_input(line)
                    buff =line.upper()
                    ETC...
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are looking for a non-blocking input method? In my opinion, a better approach would be use another thread to do the background tasks, while let `raw_input` wait for the input.

Comment: yes. Im on a RaspberryPi (among various things)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this appending a ' at the end of the print statement and then flushing the std:

```
print('                     ENTER CODE: ------\b\b\b\b\b\b'),
sys.stdout.flush()
```